# Writing to a dataframe through a loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops

I have a dataframe with two columns, one called 'name' that is a string, and one called 'route' that is a Google polyline. I'm using the polyline library to decode the polyline into lat/long. I want to loop over each row to decode but it only seems to decode only the first row and write it to the rest of the created column. This is what I have so far.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(activities)

for row in df.itertuples(index=False):

    name = row[0]
    route = row[1]

    try:
        decoded = polyline.decode(route.replace('\\\\','\\'), geojson=True)
        df['decode'] = df.apply(lambda route: [decoded], axis=1)
    except:
        print(name)
```

Comment: What is `print (df.columns)` ? If decoding failed for some row what is return? NaN? Or wrong value?

Comment: My goal for the print (name) would be to see which ones the decoder couldn't decode. Due to the fact it would only decode the first one, and then continue to write the columns until it ran out of rows, it wouldn't fail. Now that I have used your solution, it will put Nan (like you designed it to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(activities)

def decoder(name, route):
    try:
        return polyline.decode(route.replace('\\\\','\\'), geojson=True)
    except:
        print (name)
        return np.nan

 df['decode'] = df.apply(lambda x: decoder(x[0], x[1]), axis=1)
```