# decode polyline from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, polyline

I'm having a dataframe that consists of ten columns:
id  | user_id | polyline |  ...

Column "polyline" consists of the encrypted routes that can be translated into simple list of latitude / longitude. Installing polyline (e.g. via pip install) will allow to use the below code in order to get the desired lat / long.

```
import polyline
polyline.decode('onl~Fj|cvOrsEg}@rHuvK')
```

result:
[(41.84824, -87.67958), (41.81422, -87.66962), (41.81268, -87.60439)]

I'm trying to decode the polyline form the polyline column and write the last element of it (in the above example - (41.81268, -87.60439)  to a separate column.

I was trying the solution found in [Writing to a dataframe through a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61134046/writing-to-a-dataframe-through-a-loop/65255690?noredirect=1#comment115365759_65255690) but it doesn't work for me. Can you please help me with getting the desired result?

Comment: Could you please share a couple of rows of how this polyline looks like?

Comment: sorry I wasn't precise enough. I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

You can first use `map` to apply a function to each row, and then you can select the third element of its output to get the lat/long. Finally, you can split this output into lat and long respectively by selecting the value `0` and `1`. Let's suppose your dataframe contains the polylines in a column called "polyline":

```
import polyline
polyline.decode('onl~Fj|cvOrsEg}@rHuvK')

df['lat/long'] = df['polyline'].map(lambda x: polyline.decode(x)[2])
df['lat'] = df['lat/long'].str[0]
df['long'] = df['lat/long'].str[1]
```

Alternatively you can drop the `lat/long` column now that you have the individual values:

```
df = df.drop(columns='lat/long')
```

A step by step walkthrough, create sample dataframe and apply `polyline.decode(x)` to obtain the desired `lat/long` values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['A','B','C'],'Polyline':['onl~Fj|cvOrsEg}@rHuvK','onl~Fj|cvOrsEg}@rHuvK','onl~Fj|cvOrsEg}@rHuvK']})
df['lat/long'] = df['Polyline'].map(lambda x: polyline.decode(x)[2])
```

Output:

```
  Col1               Polyline               lat/long
0    A  onl~Fj|cvOrsEg}@rHuvK  (41.81268, -87.60439)
1    B  onl~Fj|cvOrsEg}@rHuvK  (41.81268, -87.60439)
2    C  onl~Fj|cvOrsEg}@rHuvK  (41.81268, -87.60439)
```

Create `lat` and `long` column with the values from `lat/long`:

```
df['lat'] = df['lat/long'].str[0]
df['long'] = df['lat/long'].str[1]
```

Output:

```
  Col1               Polyline               lat/long       lat      long
0    A  onl~Fj|cvOrsEg}@rHuvK  (41.81268, -87.60439)  41.81268 -87.60439
1    B  onl~Fj|cvOrsEg}@rHuvK  (41.81268, -87.60439)  41.81268 -87.60439
2    C  onl~Fj|cvOrsEg}@rHuvK  (41.81268, -87.60439)  41.81268 -87.60439
```

Finally deleting the `lat/long` column:

```
df = df.drop(columns='lat/long')
```

Output:

```
  Col1               Polyline       lat      long
0    A  onl~Fj|cvOrsEg}@rHuvK  41.81268 -87.60439
1    B  onl~Fj|cvOrsEg}@rHuvK  41.81268 -87.60439
2    C  onl~Fj|cvOrsEg}@rHuvK  41.81268 -87.60439
```

Comment: It looks like the solution I needed, but I'm getting one of two errors depending on what I put in the square brackets:

`rides['lat/long'] = rides['polyline'].map(lambda x: polyline.decode(x)[2])`

that gives me an error: **list index out of range** 

When I try (I think I should use [-1] as I need to get the last item from the list:

`rides['lat/long'] = rides['polyline'].map(lambda x: polyline.decode(x)[-1])`

it gives me an error: **string index out of range**

Comment: Hmm it sounds that this might happen because some of the values after using `polyline.decode(x)` aren't being properly decoded, hence returning something empty (and that's why [-1] yields index error. Perhaps we could try to solve it with with a np.where() to filter this cases. Let me update my answer in the following hours

Answer (score 0):

Based on your post, I believe the `polyline` field is a string type column. So, you can use the steps below as a base to get the data you need.

### Cretate dataframe

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["my first sentence", "it is a test", "split is fun"]})

>>> df
                   A
0  my first sentence
1       it is a test
2       split is fun
```

### Split the column into a new one

```
>>> df["new_column"] = df["A"].str.split()

>>> df
                   A             new_column
0  my first sentence  [my, first, sentence]
1       it is a test      [it, is, a, test]
2       split is fun       [split, is, fun]
```

### Create a new column with the last element of the list

```
>>> df["last_element"] = df["new_column"].str[-1]

>>> df
                   A             new_column last_element
0  my first sentence  [my, first, sentence]     sentence
1       it is a test      [it, is, a, test]         test
2       split is fun       [split, is, fun]          fun
```

You can also do it in one step, as below

```
>>> df["last_element"] = df["A"].str.split().str[-1]
```

Comment: thank you Paulo. The above steps will be helpful at the stage when I have the polylines decrypted and I'll need to separate latitude from longitude. I wasn't precise enough in my question, so I provided more details above.